# Use terminal to find and change files with a certain name

Tags: bash, replace, terminal, find

I have a directory which contains multiple folders all of which has an `app.py` file. Using the terminal I want to be able to find these files change their name to `bot.py`.

I guess I don't have to use the terminal, but don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites superuser.com OR unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: `find . -name '*app*'` and `find -exec ...` have fun :-)

Comment: Well basically `man find`

Answer (score 1):

```
while read file; do
    ...
    mv "${file}" "bot.py"

done < <(LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name 'app.py')
```

If you want to do additional steps.